# Metaplex and Solana Web3.js dependency conflict (React)

Tags: reactjs, web3js, solana-web3js, metaplex

I am developing a React app, and I have code from two different applications I wrote:

Application A uses Metaplex to find all the [NFTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token#Description) owned by a user (wallet address):

```
import { Connection as MetaConnection } from "@metaplex/js/";
import { Metadata, MetadataData } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

const lookupNfts = async () => {
    let metaConnection = new MetaConnection('mainnet-beta');
    const nftsmetadata = await Metadata.findDataByOwner(metaConnection, props.walletKey);

    // Now I have a list of NFTs via metadata
}

"dependencies": {
  "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^1.2.5",
  "@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0",
  "@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8",
  "@solana/web3.js": "^1.35.3",
}
```

Application B does a payment between wallets of an NFT:

```
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Account } from "@solana/spl-token";   // ERROR on this line, see screenshot

async function transfer_tokens(wallet: Keypair, connection: Connection, amount: number, reciver_token_account: Account, from_token_account: Account) {
// If tx takes more when 60 seconds to complete you will receive error here
const transfer_tx = await splToken.transfer(
    connection,
    wallet,
    from_token_account.address,
    reciver_token_account.address,
    wallet,
    amount,
    [wallet],
    false,
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
)
```

[image]

However, when I try to use this code together in one application, it doesn’t work...

There seems to be a conflict. The dependency from application A pulls in `@solana/spl-token@0.1.8`, but application B requires `@solana/spl-token@0.2.0`.

If I upgrade solana/spl-token to 0.2.0, application A breaks.
If I keep solana/spl-token at 0.1.8, application B doesn’t work.

I did a *npm ls*, and it shows this:

[image]

It seems the metaplex/js@4.12.0 has a dependency to 0.1.8, which is old.

How can I resolve this dependency conflict?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72217359/edit) (it covers command lines and program text output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@metaplex/js` library uses old versions of MPL packages such as `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` which, as you figured out, use an old version of `@solana/spl-token`. Unfortunately, if even just one nested dependency uses version `0.1.8` of the SPL token program, it will be used for the entire project.

If you are using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), a quick fix could be to force version `0.2.0` using the `resolutions` object in your `package.json`.

```json
"resolutions": {
  "@solana/spl-token": "0.2.0"
}
```

If you're using `npm`, you will also need to [install this package](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions).

However, it is worth noting that the current JavaScript SDK from Metaplex is going to be deprecated in favour of the new one: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-next

With the new JS SDK, you can fetch all NFTs by owner using the following piece of code.

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js-next";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
const owner = new PublicKey("some_public_key");

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(owner);
```